# Struts2 - How access a nested enum

Tags: java, struts2, enums, nested, html-select

I'm creating a `<s:select>` tag, usually i pass the full path of an enum as follows:

```
<s:select 
    name="name" 
    label="%{getText('myClass.label')}"
    list="@fullpath.MyEnum@values()" 
    listValue="%{getText(name())}"  
    headerValue="%{getText('seleziona')}" 
    headerKey="" 
/>
```

How do i access a nested enum? My current class is:

```
public class myClass{
    //some fields
    public enum MyEnum{
        //fields
    }
}
```

I tried doing `list="@fullpath.MyClass.MyEnum@values()"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$` dollar sing to access inner classes.

```
list="@fullpath.MyClass$MyEnum@values()"
```

Note: Your class should start with capital letter.

```
public class MyClass{
    //some fields
    public enum MyEnum{
        //fields
    }
}
```

Comment: sure, my class starts with capital... :) it was only a type error